# How to return an array of strings in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, graphql

So I'm trying to figure out how to return an array of strings in GraphQL. Basically I have a to-do list with dependencies, so for each item there's a list of things that other item relies on by ID. I'm a little new to all this, but I've done a lot of searching on the GraphQL docs and on here and haven't found anything yet, so apologies in advance if this is a dumb question. I'm using lodash in the resolve function.

```
// dummy data
var todos = [
  { name: 'Repair Driveway', dependencies: ['2' ,'3'], id: '1' },
  { name: 'Research driveway repair', dependencies: [], id: '2' },
  { name: 'Buy driveway repair tools', dependencies: ['2'], id: '3' },
  { name: 'Get groceries', dependencies: [], id: '4'}
];

const TodoType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Todo',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    deadline: { type: GraphQLDateTime },
    dependencies: { type:   } // This is where I'm not sure what to do.
  })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    todo: {
      type: TodoType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
      resolve(parent, args){
        console.log("Queried:" );
        return _.find(todos, { id: args.id });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphQL provides a class that makes a lists of a given object type `new GraphQLList(objectType)`.

You can use it like:

```
const TodoType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Todo',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    deadline: { type: GraphQLDateTime },
    dependencies: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)  }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const TodoType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Todo',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        deadline: { type: GraphQLDateTime },
        dependencies: { type: [GraphQLString!] } // This is where I'm not sure what to do.
    })
});
```

Hope it helps